# How do I make a copy of a google sheet tab and rename it

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here is my code, Im trying to get the oldmonthtab to copy itself and name itself to the newmonthname, but I just cant figure out how to get that last part to work.

````
  var oldMonthName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("X2").getRange("U4").getValue();//name for the old month, formula in X2
  var newMonthName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("X2").getRange("U3").getValue();//name for new month, formula in X2
  var oldMonthTab = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(oldMonthName);//old month tab, used to be able to hide it
  
  var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1lQ10rgciG5WiUQ0uVQc1E7r7Qwd6hOkZQSaH');//chooses this spreadsheet, the ID should come from the URL of the sheet it will be copied to.
  oldMonthTab.copyTo(destination).setname(newMonthTab);//makes a copy of old month and sets the name to new month```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `newMonthTab` is undefined. Use this:

```
  oldMonthTab.copyTo(destination).setName(newMonthName);
```

Comment: ah yes, thanks. that was one issue, but its still giving me an error in the debugger.

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'copyTo')
newMonth @ new month nix old.gs:8

Comment: 4:52:09 PM Error 
TypeError: oldMonthTab.copyTo(...).setname is not a function
newMonth @ new month nix old.gs:8

Comment: The first error tells that there is no sheet by that name in the spreadsheet. The second error tells that you should use `.setName()` instead of `.setname()`.